# How to fix: check_and_cast(): cannot cast NULL pointer to type 'IPv4ControlInfo *'

Tags: routes, omnet++, inet

This is a replay method I implemented into AODVRouting.cc (already in inet). When I launch the simulation, it runs for a little while but then I get this error:

```
check_and_cast(): cannot cast NULL pointer to type 'IPv4ControlInfo *'
```

This is my method:

```
void AODVRouting::Replay (cMessage *msg)
{
        std::cout<<"Mal Host Activity"<<endl;
        EV <<"Mal Host Activity \n";
        this->bubble("Replaying...");
        this->host->setDisplayString("i=misc/node,red");

            cMessage *ReplayMsg = msg->dup();
            std::cout<<"Done Duplicating MSG"<<endl;
            EV<<"Done Duplicating MSG \n";


            //we can add a delay before sending the copy of the message again (10 time units)
            //scheduleAt(simTime() + 1, ReplayMsg);
            send(ReplayMsg, "ipOut");
            //sendDelayed(ReplayMsg, 0.01,"ipOut");

            std::cout<<"Launched Replayed Packet!\n";
            EV<<"Launched Replayed Packet!\n";
            this->bubble("Attack");
}
```

Any ideas how to fix the error?

Comment: Did you try debugging your simulation model?

Comment: One error leads to another... I think I'm checking the destination address in the wrong way. Not sure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ipv4address was pointing to a null factor - packet is destroyed prior to reaching the command I'm attempting. 
I found a fix by referring to the index instead of the IP using:
getIndex()